# "No such file or directory" with firebase_admin python library

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I want to retrieve some data by a firebase database with using the official library for python (`firebase_admin`) instead of `pyrebase` or `python-firebase`.

I try to execute the following lines of code:

```
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import credentials
import firebase_admin

cred = credentials.Certificate('https://project_name.firebaseio.com/.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

result = db.Query.get()
```

but then I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://project_name.firebaseio.com/.json'
```

even though when I enter this url on my browser (with `project_name` replaced with my real project name) I am getting the json of data from the database.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Certificate` should point to a **local** file with your credentials/certificate. You are instead pointing it to your database URL, which is not a local file, so the library throws an error.

From the [documentation on initializing the Python SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start):

> ```
> import firebase_admin
> from firebase_admin import credentials
> from firebase_admin import db
>
> # Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
> cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
>
> # Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
> firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
>     'databaseURL': 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com'
> })
>
> # As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
> ref = db.reference('restricted_access/secret_document')
> print(ref.get())
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Frank (upvote). What you are saying makes sense for sure. Could you please explain a little bit more at your post what this json file should contain? The funny thing is that I have (manually) direct access to the database by using a url like this `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/name/database/name/data` (where name are the name of the project or the db) but I was stuck a little bit with how to do this with `firebase_admin`.

Comment: The file contains the credentials that allow access to your project. See the documentation on how to get the file here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,this works for me

> ```
> import os
> from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, initialize_app
>
> # Initialize Firestore DB
> data = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/serviceAccountKey.json"
> cred = credentials.Certificate(data)
> default_app = initialize_app(cred)
> db = firestore.client()
> ```

Comment: Please add a description of how your method fixes the issue

Comment: add the path like this ,
data = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/serviceAccountKey.json"